# Basic I really need to know to use Python scripting in Blender

Tags: python

What are all the basic I need to know in Python to be able to use Blenders Python  to start to get comfortably

Yes I heard 
 The following 
The print statements (" type anything between double brackets and double quotes  ")
Variables
a Text string variable
 fun = ("blender is fun")
print(fun)

a number variable 
a = 7
print(a)

Int type is a  integer 25
Float type is a number with a  decimal .25

Booleans 
True 
False

Comment: There are many Python tutorials on the web - for example https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/ . Once you're familiar with Python you can start on bpy (Blender Python).

Comment: Any python tutorial can get you started, you can follow any of the python intro tutorials using blender, it has a [text editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/text_editor.html) and [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/python_console.html). When you get to importing and using external modules, the same is applied to [blender's api](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/) which is what you want to get familiar with.

Comment: Thank You Sir very much for the links I just made notes of them for record

Comment: I been told I need to know some kind of 3d math do you have any links for that I wanted to learn just enough 3D math  Believe it's called vectors math and matrices anthing else that will Be needed to so I can start have more control over the axis in 3d space  coordinates system ?  my math is not that great  but is there in way to do any kind of  Visual inner active programming with in blender  with visual feedback using  scripting python nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Well beside sometime sparse documentation most useful thing you'll get to learn objects/operations is to turn Blender global display (top menu right after "help" dropdown) to **"Scripting"**

Now you will see some **"log screen"** on top of your screen area, it will enumerate a lot of bpy.ops;

For example moving selected object will produce:

```
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0.2785, 0, 0), 
constraint_axis=(True, False, False), 
constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', 
mirror=False, 
proportional='DISABLED', 
proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', 
proportional_size=1, 
release_confirm=(True)
)
```

Which is a valid blender python command.

You'll also have on bottom of screen scripting console to test things live with autocomplete/autodocumentation feature on functions you'll type.